# papyal - Multiple agreements in one checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible for a user to sign multiple billing agreements in one checkout?

We've got three different subscriptions that can be combined together. Having to create a unique billing plan that permutates all the different combinations is hardly ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, the answer is No ...